# How to add Gravity forms gform_pre_render action in a plugin file

Tags: gravityforms

I am new to wordpress and this might be a really simple task.
I have a created a form using gravity forms plugin. I need to populate an options field in the form by making an API call. I had implemented this using gform_pre_render action and calling the function to make the API call. This code was in funtions.php of the active theme. This was working as expected.

However, now I'm required to do the same in a plugin file as I cannot have custom code in the themes file. When I place the same code in a plugin file and install the plugin, I am not getting the options field populated by API.
Is there any other way to do this? Please let me know. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gform_pre_render` hook to add your custom code to the plugin. The only difference is that you need to use the `add_filter` function instead of `add_action`:

```php
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'populate_options' );
```

The `add_filter` function is the same as `add_action` except that it expects a callback function that returns a value. In the case of the `gform_pre_render` hook, the callback function should return the form object.

So, the code you want to run when the form is rendered should look something like this:

```php
function populate_options( $form ) {
    // your code goes here
    return $form;
}
```